# converting a python list to a SQL database

Tags: python, sql, database, list, sqlite

Using python, I am trying to convert a list to an sql database. The current questions I read did not work for me...

I have a list, called "datab" and I am trying to read it in using

```
conn = sqlite3.connect('database.db')
c = conn.cursor() 
c.execute("DROP TABLE g")
c.execute("""CREATE TABLE g
              (story_type, estimate, kind, name, accepted_at,
               url, created_at, labels, current_state, updated_at,         
               owned_by_id,requested_by_id,id,owner_id) 
           """)
c.executemany("INSERT INTO g VALUES (?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?,?)", datab)
```

but it keeps giving me an error

```
Incorrect number of bindings supplied. The current statement uses 14, and there are 12 supplied.
```

I think it has something to do with my table. I included the line

```
   c.execute("DROP TABLE g")
```

because without it, it gives me an error saying there is already a table named "g"

Can anyone explain to me what a "binding" is and why I only supplied twelve of them?

EDIT: 
I defined datab as

```
datab = [story_type, estimate, kind, name, accepted_at,
               url, created_at, labels, current_state, updated_at,         
               owned_by_id,requested_by_id,the_id,owner_id]
```

each of these elements is a list iself.

I see now that datab has twelve elements in it. I think I am telling it to insert the first list as the first row. How do I change this so that I am inserting the first list as the first column?

Comment: I don't know why you want to drop and recreate the table each time. But that's not where the error is happening; it's in the INSERT statement, presumably because datab only has 12 elements.

Comment: `.executemany` requires a sequence of items each containing 14 items...

Comment: Your create table has 12 columns, but your execute has 14 question marks.

Answer (score 0):

`executemany` requires a list of rows.

To convert your data into this format, try `zip(*datab)`.